# How to explain and possibly avoid undervoltage on I2C bus?

Tags: sensor, i2c, logic-level

I've been testing different sensors for the I²C bus with two host devices: Raspberry Pi 3B (3.3V), and Sitec S4 (5.0V).

Since one of them, namely the Sensirion SCD30, had communication problems every few seconds, I looked at the bus with a scope and found that the voltage both on SDA and SCL drops below ground level to about -0.3V at the beginning of each communication.
Here is what the scope showed:
[image: Scope image of I2C communication between Raspi and SCD30]
There is no difference when all devices and cables are diconnected from the I²C bus, except for the obvious fact the the host does not receive an answer when using `i2cdetect`.

The [I²C specification](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/user-guide/UM10204.pdf) allows the low level voltage to drop to -0.5V, so this undervoltage should not be a problem.
The [SCD30](https://www.sensirion.com/fileadmin/user_upload/customers/sensirion/Dokumente/0_Datasheets/CO2/Sensirion_CO2_Sensors_SCD30_Datasheet.pdf) only accepts a low level voltage above -0.3V, so this is most presumably what is causing trouble.

[EDIT] I have experimented a bit with series resistors in the bus lines (22R and 100R). 100R rounden the signals too much, but with 22R series resistance both in SDA and SCL, it looks a bit better:
[image: Scope image of I2C communication of Raspi, 22R series]

[EDIT2] The communication problem seems to be caused by clock stretching, not by the undervoltage. This is what a regular transmission looks in detail:
[image: Scope image of I2C communication of Raspi with SCD30, works]
When clock stretching has not been enabled as described [here](https://raspihats.com/i2c-hat/2016/02/16/raspberry-pi-i2c-clock-stretch-timeout.html), there are communication failures. Undervoltage does not seem to be the cause.

My problem is probably solved, but the original questions are open:

1. What causes the undervoltage? (Inductance?)
2. Is it possible (though not necessary) the make sure that the I²C bus voltage does not drop below a certain level, e.g. be adding a diode between each bus line and ground with a low enough forward voltage? Such devices seem to be difficult to find...

Comment: It may not be a real voltage but just a problem with the way you are grounding your measurement. IMO voltage below ground is probably not the cause of your communication issues. (But it may be a symptom of a common problem)

Comment: Are all of the devices on the bus using the same supply voltage?

Comment: I thought of a measurement problem, too, but the scope's probes' ground clamps are firmly attached to a central ground point.
And yes, all devices including the host use a single laboratory power supply.
Please note that I have the same behavior with no devices connected to the bus - just the probes attached to the host's I²C and ground pins.

Comment: I agree that what you're seeing on the scope should work; I'm not worried about what appears to be a hybrid capacitive coupling that throws your a few tenths out of range after a long period at one level.  I'd like to see the schematic, the error patterns, and a faster scope trace where we could compare clock edges with data edges.  The voltage variation is interesting, but it may not be at proximate cause.

Comment: Assuming that I have understood @CristobolPolychronopolis correctly, I have recorded new measurements with the scope with a shorter time/div, and indeed it seems that my problem is caused by something else: The I²C clock frequency seems to be 111kHz normally (~9µs cycle time), but every now and then jumps to 167kHz (~6µs), in which case communication errors occur.
That does not seem to bring us any closer to an answer to my original question on undervoltage, but still helps me of course. I'm going to check if it's the same on the other host.

Comment: @gunnar_arndt, You can edit your post to add updates to your screenshots and other observations, if you still want our help.

Comment: The mentioned clock cycle issue is caused by the SCD30 stretching the clock, which does not work on the Raspi reliably, but seems to be fixable: [link](https://raspihats.com/i2c-hat/2016/02/16/raspberry-pi-i2c-clock-stretch-timeout.html)

Comment: Glad you figured it out. Clock stretching is one of those weird corner cases that are often not properly supported. I would expect clock stretching to cause the period to increase, not decrease, though.

Comment: It looks like your scope probe compensation is off. Simply forget about this "undervoltage". it is likely a measurement artifact.

Comment: @Justin, you assume correctly that stretching should increase the period of a single clock cycle. What can happen in case of the Raspi confronted to a clock stretching slave is that the period changes for multiple cycles during a complete message sometimes. I'll see if I can add a picture of that too - but maybe I should split this thread in two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Ale..chenski is right: After freshly compensating the probes, the undervoltage was gone.
I had compensated the probes with the attenuation set to 1x, at which setting they were still perfect, but had recently switched to 10x, not knowing that this requires recalibration.
The I²C communication problem could be fixed by turning on clock stretching, as described in the updated question.
Thanks everybody.